# Почему функция ругается на двумерный массив (в параметре функции)? (Функция для заполнения двумерного массива случайными числами)

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, параметры

При создании программы заполнения двумерного массива случайными числами, столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу передать массив для функции. В параметрах функции выдает ошибку возле массива: "Массив не может содержать элементы этого типа".
Подскажите что я сделал неправильно.

```
void ArrFill(int arr[][], int rows, int cols)
{
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = 30 + rand() % 60;
        cout << arr[i][j] << "/t";
    }
    cout << endl;
```

}

Comment: Неправильно передали массив. Нужно как минимум указывать размеры кроме одного - т.е. `void ArrFill(int arr[][100]`, скажем. Или передавать просто `int*` и считать индекс элемента `[i][j]`...

Comment: а если в меня есть в Int main() константа const int ROWS как мне её передать то?

Comment: Передать массив в функцию по значению нельзя. Передавайте указатель или ссылку или view/

Comment: В языке С++ в принципе не бывает массивов `[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

Данное объявление двумерного массива в качестве параметра

```
void ArrFill(int arr[][], int rows, int cols)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

некорректное.

Все размерности массива кроме крайней левой должны быть указаны и быть константными значениями. C++ к тому же не поддерживает массивы переменной длины.

Вы могли бы объявить функцию следующим образом:

```
const size_t Cols = /*...*/;
void ArrFill( int arr[][Cols], size_t rows );
```

Кроме того символ табуляции - это не этот символ `'/t'`, а этот символ `'\t'`.

Вы можете себе значительно упростить жизнь, если объявите шаблонную функцию вида

```
template <size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void ArrFill( int ( &arr )[Rows][Cols], std::pair<int, int> range )
{
    std::srand( std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &row : arr )
    {
        for ( auto &item : row )
        {
            item = range.first + std::rand() % ( range.second - range.first );
            std::cout << item << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

template <size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void ArrFill( int ( &arr )[Rows][Cols], std::pair<int, int> range )
{
    std::srand( std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &row : arr )
    {
        for ( auto &item : row )
        {
            item = range.first + std::rand() % ( range.second - range.first );
            std::cout << item << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}       

int main() 
{
    const size_t Rows = 10, Cols = 10;
    int arr[Rows][Cols];

    ArrFill( arr, { 30, 90 } );

    return 0;
}
```

вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть, к примеру, следующим образом:

```
84  44  65  61  72  62  87  30  88  72  
84  85  72  49  46  63  67  71  37  35  
73  32  49  57  61  63  47  64  67  76  
81  53  30  48  84  73  80  82  65  71  
56  60  66  38  71  74  63  40  56  62  
45  31  64  56  50  35  30  67  62  59  
53  45  82  54  64  76  89  46  60  64  
87  86  86  55  86  68  40  59  78  58  
31  86  59  58  52  79  63  44  49  87  
73  72  43  65  88  77  44  87  33  74
```